# How to replace specific character in pandas column with null?

Tags: python, database, pandas, replace

I Have a column within a dataset, regarding categorical company sizes, which currently looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKh5m.png), where the '-' hyphens are currently representing missing data:

I want to change the '-' in missing values with nulls so i can analyse missing data. However when I use the pd replace tool (see following code) with a None value it seems to also make any of the genuine entries as they also contain hyphens (e.g 51-200).

```
df['Company Size'].replace({'-': None},inplace =True, regex= True)
```

How can I replace only lone standing hyphens and leave the other entries untouched?

Comment: don't use `regex = True`. that is for substring

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need not to use regex=True.

```
df['Company Size'].replace({'-': None},inplace =True)
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.

Comment: To add to this: I just lost a lot of time to discover that None doesn't seem to work outside of a dictionary. Using pandas 0.23.4, `.replace(to_replace='#####', value=None)` didn't work, but `.replace({'#####': None})` did.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just do:

`df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].replace('-','None')`

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

df.replace('-', np.NaN, inplace=True)
```

This code worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                   'C': ['a', '-', 'c--', 'd', 'e']})

df['C'] = df['C'].replace('-', np.nan)
df = df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None) 
# can also use this -> df['C'] = df['C'].where((pd.notnull(df)), None)

print(df)
```

output:

```
   A  B     C
0  0  5     a
1  1  6  None
2  2  7   c--
3  3  8     d
4  4  9     e
```

**another example:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': ['5-5', '-', 7, 8, 9],
                   'C': ['a', 'b', 'c--', 'd', 'e']})

df['B'] = df['B'].replace('-', np.nan)
df = df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None)
print(df)
```

output:

```
   A     B    C
0  0   5-5    a
1  1  None    b
2  2     7  c--
3  3     8    d
4  4     9    e
```